# Why does this C++ program compile on MacOS but not Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, macos, ubuntu, default-constructor

I am using Clang version 10 on Ubuntu and MacOS machines:

```
ubuntu $ clang++ --version
clang version 10.0.0-++20200227124856+593a0dda7a6-1~exp1~20200227115450.103
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

```
osx $ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

The following simple program does not compile on Ubuntu (16.04), but does on MacOS 10.14:

```
// test.cpp

#include <atomic>
struct foo {

  bool bar;
  int baz;
  foo(bool bar, int baz) : bar(bar), baz(baz) {
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::atomic<foo> test_struct({false, 0});
  test_struct.load();

  return 0;
}
```

I am compiling with

```
clang++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test
```

The error on Ubuntu is

```
In file included from test.cpp:1:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/atomic:234:13: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'foo'
        _Tp tmp;
            ^
test.cpp:13:11: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::atomic<foo>::load' requested here
  test_struct.load();
          ^
test.cpp:2:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
struct foo {
       ^
test.cpp:2:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
test.cpp:6:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 0 were provided
  foo(bool bar, bool baz) :
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Am I running into some undefined behaviour here? Or what measures do I need to take to make the two scenarios completely equal?

**Edit** I can make this compile by adding a default constructor to the type. However I cannot parse this requirement from [`std::atomic`s documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) and I  am confused why the default constructor appears to be generated on MacOS but not on Ubuntu.

Comment: I get `error: ‘proceed’ was not declared in this scope`. Is that a [mre]?

Comment: Oops, sorry, fixed.

Comment: Please compile with `clang++ -Wall -Wextra` or `g++ -Wall -Wextra` and study *carefully* some C++11 standard, perhaps [n3337](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n3337.pdf). Then upgrade your C++ compilers. For [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) the current version is [GCC  9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/) in 1Q2020. Your GCC seems too old! Try `g++ --version `

Comment: are you sure you're compiling **this** code on Ubuntu? The error message says `std::atomic<action_t>`

Comment: In Ubuntu you seem to have an old version of the library. See e.g. [clang 9](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fZbbMN91O06Huhcm) vs. [gcc 5.4](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2NqxL5fuE5s3F8tf).

Comment: Even this line fails: `std::atomic<foo> test_struct;`. This is because the implementation of `atomic` uses default constructed value, which is incorrect and probably fixed in a newer version.

Comment: @bolov I renamed the stuff for the question and forgot to update the error. Fixed.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am using clang, not gcc. I specifically updated clang to version 10 to see if that was the issue. Also C++14, not 11

Comment: @oarfish on ubuntu clang links by default against `libstdc++` which is GNU's implementation of C++ standard library. You have take extra steps in order to link against `libc++` which is llvm's C++ standard library. https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html

Comment: Actually I also tried `-stdlib=libc++`, which results in `test.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'atomic' file not found`. Could that be an outdated LLVM standard library? I would assume installing clang 10 from LLVMs apt repooository would also install the up-to-date libc++ version.

Comment: @oarfish nope, you need to properly install it as they are separate packages. See https://apt.llvm.org/

Comment: You are correct. Installing/upgrading `libc++-dev` fixed the problem, so the answer is indeed "Outdated standard library". The fix in this case would be to install  an updated GNU `libstdc++` I assume?

Comment: yeah, if you want to link against libstdc++ you need up upgrade it. You can answer your own question so it doesn't remain open.

Comment: I could, but I don't want to steal the reputation from the commenters.

Comment: @oarfish don't worry about it. It is encouraged to answer your own question if you found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that on Linux systems, `clang` links against the GNU C++ standard library implementation `libstc++`, which in this case is too old (version 5.4. or some such) and does not work with the language standard selected (`c++14`).

There are two solutions:

1. Somehow install an updated `libstdc++`, which may or may not be in the APT package repositories for the Ubuntu version (in my case there is no newer version)
2. Make `clang` use the LLVM implementation `libc++`. Make sure there is a recent version installed (package `libc++-dev`) and pass `-stdlib=libc++` during compilation.